# Is it possible to define a TFS instance as Development?

Tags: plugins, tfs, server-side

I am writing/testing a server side plug-in and am looking to derive if this is running on our development or production TFS instance to allow me to drive a slightly different process (e.g. add some obvious text to any email subjects that it sends out to ensure that people know it has derived from the development instance).

There is a "IsProduction" property that I can access via the requestContext variable (IVSSRequestContext.ServiceHost.IsProduction - was previously TeamFoundationRequestContext.TeamFoundationServicehost.IsProduction before TFS2015), but this property is set to true in both instances.

Does anyone know if/should this can be used for that purpose and if so, how it can be set as I can't find any documentation online and can't see anything obvious in the TFS Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

No, but I suggest using a global Environment variable (e.g. `IsDevelopment`).
Another option is to get the server URL (see code snippet) and use it to determine the environment, but I think it is less safe.

`private Uri GetCollectionUriFromContext(IVssRequestContext requestContext)
{
  ILocationService service = requestContext.GetService<ILocationService>();
  return service.GetSelfReferenceUri(requestContext,
    service.GetDefaultAccessMapping(requestContext));
}`

Comment: IMHO `IsProduction` is used by MS in VSTS code and there has different values.